# List as value in dictionary, get key of longest list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Give a dictionary like this

```
testDict = {76: [4], 32: [2, 4, 7, 3], 56: [2, 58, 59]}
```

How do I get the key of the longest list? In this case it would be `32`.

Comment: What do you want to happen in case there are multiple keys whose associated values have the maximum length?

Comment: Good question. I want to get multiple keys then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `max`:

```
>>> max(testDict, key=lambda x:len(testDict[x]))
32
```

If multiple keys contain the longest list:

> I want to get multiple keys then.

```
>>> testDict = {76: [4], 32: [2, 4, 7, 3], 56: [2, 58, 59], 10: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> mx = max(len(x) for x in testDict.itervalues())
>>> [k for k, v in testDict.iteritems() if len(v)==mx]
[32, 10]
```