# How to Find Key in Python Dictionary with Most Amount of Values (Not the Highest)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Suppose we have this dictionary (a sample of a larger one):

```
dic = {
  0: [2324, 4353, 342]
  1: [242453, 542]
  2: [44, 353, 5342, 5342, 5342, 534]}
```

I'd like have 2 (the key) returned as it is the key with the most amount of values (6). So, the output ideally looks like:

```
2: 6
```

(Key 2, 6 values).

How can this be done in Python?

I've tried doing e.g. `print(len(dic[0]))`, and it returns 3. But, what I want is for Python to go through each key and return the biggest length for me, without having to manually go through each.

Comment: `max(dic, key=lambda x: len(dic[x]))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List as value in dictionary, get key of longest list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845258/list-as-value-in-dictionary-get-key-of-longest-list)

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function with a custom `key`:

```
dic = {0: [2324, 4353, 342],
       1: [242453, 542],
       2: [44, 353, 5342, 5342, 5342, 534]}    
print(max(dic.items(), key=lambda v: len(v[1]))[0])
```

should print

```
2
```

Basically you are telling the `max` function to use the length of the second (`[1]`) value in the tuple when comparing elements. The `.items()` method converts the dictionary to an iterator of tuples, so the first element is the key and the second element is the value.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have your data in format similear to that:

```
data = {
     0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     1: [1, 2, 5],
     2: [1, 6, 9, 3, 8, 9],
     5: [7]
}
```

Next step could be to make dict that is containing pair "key: len(value)" where key and value is given by original data dict, eg like that:

```
dict_of_key_length_pairs = {k: len(v) for k, v in data.items()}
print(dict_of_key_length_pairs)

{0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 6, 5: 1}
```

And then we need to get key for maximum value (eg which is 6 with the key 2):

```
max(dict_of_key_length_pairs, key=dict_of_key_length_pairs.get)
```